# Spectrum of light has red colour at one end. Why should it have violet colour (combination of red and blue) at the other end?

Tags: visible-light

From one end of the light spectrum colours keep on changing with the red colour at one end. It is anomalous that the colour at the other end should be also a combination of the red colour because violet colour is a combination of red and blue colours.

Comment: From my previous life as a TV repairman, I seem to recall that illuminating the red and blue phosphors of a color CRT yielded [*magenta*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magenta) (for completeness, red + green = yellow and blue + green = cyan).  From the linked Wikipedia article:  *"Magenta is an extra-spectral color, meaning that it is not found in the visible spectrum of light"*

Answer (score 2):

The violet light at the end of the rainbow is emphatically **not** a combination of red and blue light. The photons are all roughly the same wavelength (roughly 400 nm), which corresponds to violet as seen by the human eye.

The reason we **see** red and blue light as violet is because our eyes are essentially made up of three types of sensors which respond in certain ways to certain wavelengths. When a combination of red and blue light hits our eye, it produces the same response from those sensors as violet light, but is not by any means the same light.

Comment: And yes, I am aware that red and blue makes magenta, not violet. Just insert whatever color combination makes your eyes see violet, and the rest of the answer is pretty much unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Violet PIGMENTs are a mix of red and blue. Light mixes differently, in essentially the opposite way.
Take a look here:
https://sites.google.com/site/scienceofcolour/how-colors-mix

Answer (score 0):

As many others have said light mix is completely different than pigments. See this video https://youtu.be/IWe_N_hHKqs 
The reason has to do with the way our eyes react to different frequency photons. In the video you see yellow because your eyes are still receiving red and green photons. After you mix the two liquids together your eyes can only see One color photons all at the same frequency which looks purpleish brown.

Answer (score 0):

You may like to know that I finally got real answer to my question at the following URLs.

(i) http://shutha.org/node/815

(ii)    https://www.stinkyinkshop.co.uk/blog/how-cmyk-and-rgb-colours-affect-printing-your-photos/.

The authors of these articles have explained that the colours of the visible electromagnetic waves (light) are additive colours but the colours of the pigments are subtractive colours. When the three primary additive Red, Green and Blue colours are mixed in equal ratio we get white colour but when we mix the three subtractive colours we get black colour.  So the purple colour we see at the end of the rainbow is actually not arrived by mixing the additive Red and additive Blue colours. Of course they have not mentioned that white colour also gets generated by mixing the subtractive colours “Red, Green and Blue” or “Magenta, Yellow and Cyan” in some specific ratio instead of equal ratio.

Answer (score 0):

The [electromagnetic spectrum](https://science-edu.larc.nasa.gov/EDDOCS/Wavelengths_for_Colors.html) corresponds to definite frequencies/wavelengths and in the visible there is one to one correspondence with the color names given to our perception of color. Each frequency/wavelength   of the visible spectrum gives a unique color in our eye.

[image: spectrum]

where λ = c/ν ,  λ  the wavelength, c velocity of ligth, ν frequency

So color perception is different than the color map of the electromagnetic spectrum.

When more than one frequency hits the eye receptors, [color perception](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/vision/colper.html) comes to play, because of the biological nature of "seeing".

[image: colorpercetptio]